# Pass Google Sheets Cell Value To HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell

I am trying to pass the value "assetCell" to the HTML dialog box. It seems simple enough . . . thank you for any help.

GAS

```
 function Test(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var MySH = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var Assetcell = MySH.getRange("f8").getValue()
 var Assetcellb = MySH.getRange("f10").getValue()

 var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('vIndex'); // Modified
 t.AssetCell = Assetcell 
 t.AssetCell = Assetcellb

 html = t.evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(300); // Added

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
.showModalDialog(html, 'Hi');
 }
```

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
 <body>
 <?!= AssetCell => ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### GAS

```
function Test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var MySH = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var Assetcell = MySH.getRange("f8").getValue()

  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('vIndex'); // Modified
  t.AssetCell = Assetcell; // Added
  html = t.evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(300); // Added

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Hi');
}
```

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?!= AssetCell ?> => <!-- Modified -->
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Reference :

- [createTemplateFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createTemplateFromFile(String))

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

#### 1. When you want to give them to `<?!= AssetCell ?>`

You can use the same HTML.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var MySH = ss.getActiveSheet();
var Assetcell1 = MySH.getRange("f8").getValue();
var Assetcell2 = MySH.getRange("f10").getValue();

var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('vIndex'); // Modified
t.AssetCell = [Assetcell1, Assetcell2]; // Added
html = t.evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(300); // Added

SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .showModalDialog(html, 'Hi');
```

#### 2. When you want to give `<?!= AssetCell1 ?>` and `<?!= AssetCell2 ?>`, respectively

GAS

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var MySH = ss.getActiveSheet();
var Assetcell1 = MySH.getRange("f8").getValue();
var Assetcell2 = MySH.getRange("f10").getValue();

var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('vIndex'); // Modified
t.AssetCell1 = Assetcell1; // Added
t.AssetCell2 = Assetcell2; // Added
html = t.evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(300); // Added

SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .showModalDialog(html, 'Hi');
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?!= AssetCell1 ?> => <!-- Modified -->
    <?!= AssetCell2 ?> => <!-- Modified -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tanaike - please accept my gratitude; your modification worked just perfectly!! Thank You!

Comment: Tanaike - if I may ask a follow up. What if I wished to pass the value of TWO cells. I tried to modify your code - but I receive an error. If it is not an imposition, would be able to  offer a suggestion? I will edit my original code with what I have tried.

Comment: @Tacitus I'm sorry. I have no information about "TWO cell" for your next question. If you want to use like ``var Assetcell = MySH.getRange("f8:f9").getValues();``, the script works. So can I ask you about the detail information?

Comment: I am sorry - I was not clear. If I wished to pass the value of F8 and F10; how would I adjust the code, please?

Comment: @Tacitus I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If this modification is not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Tanaike - YES!! Your modifications worked just perfectly once more. Thank You, Tanaike! Please note I have marked the solution "Accepted".  Thank You, friend!

Comment: @Tanaike. another day, another time your code rescued ordinary developers like me. This is a very elegant solution. Though I stumbled upon it after couple of hours of hitting my head in the dark.